# base64, hexadecimal o byte[ ] para un return de webservices

Tags: java, webservice, java-ee

Tengo un WSDL que genera un PDF de jasperreport y lo envía a mi servlet, entonces me gustaría cual es la forma más optima para enviar el pdf, tengo 3 opciones:
base64, hexadecimal o byte[].
Supongo que entre las dos primeras está la respuesta, ya que con el byte [] puedo perder datos, o quizás me equivoco.

Comment: la opción de byte te puede generar problemas con caracteres extraños, aunque creo que hay alguna clase de axis que resuelve eso pero no estoy seguro. Con base64 es mas pesado pero aseguras el envió, en hexadecimal nunca lo había oído  pero si usa el mismo principio que base64(por el nombre) pero con base16 obviamente será aún mas pesado que base64 por lo que de estos 3  recomiendo base64.

Comment: @abrahamhs gracias por la respuesta, bro! Usaré base64, ya que es re simple usando Base64.encodeBase64String de apache commons codec